# Is this photograph of Frank Sinatra as a 10 year old real?

Tags: history, photography

There is an image of Frank Sinatra floating around the internet in its usual unattributed copyright-infringing fashion:

[image: Frank Sinatra at 10 years old]

No doubt there are pictures out there of Frank Sinatra as a young boy, but my questions is is *this* picture of Frank Sinatra in his iconic "fedora and suit" real, or is it photoshopped together from a photo of a young Frank Sinatra, and a child styling his iconic look?

Is there an original source for this photograph?

Comment: What kind of evidence would convince you if that picture is authentic or not?

Comment: @georgechalhoub A source for the photograph would certainly help (with a copy that hasn't been cropped and cropped every time a watermark or hosting website's url has been added to the bottom of the image). As for disproving it, all it would take is one photograph that looks "a bit too similar" to this one.

Comment: I have found the picture sourced as: Michael Ochs Archives/Getty Images, Frank Sinatra in 1922 - see http://www.chicagotribune.com/entertainment/music/reich/ct-sinatra-centennial-20150125-column.html#page=1 The article is recent, but the attribution might prove helpful when tracing the origin.

Comment: There is also a similiar picture, from a different angle, at https://bornvintage.wordpress.com/2012/10/26/guess-who/ (also http://classichollywoodcentral.com/?p=1884) - I did not try to source this one.

Comment: @Suma That'll do very nicely, indeed! If you can find the source for the second image, you have the makings of a very acceptable answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there an original source for this photograph?

Fortunately, there is. This photo is originated from an [official source](http://www.antiquecollectorsclub.com/us/store/productdatasheet/9781851498031).

Frank Sinatra was honored with an official $1,500 book limited with 1,000 copies.

[image]

The book's description is:

> The **official** luxury **book** to commemorate the Frank Sinatra centenary, limited to just 1000 copies, in a deluxe clam-shell box, **accompanied by a previously unpublished photograp**h, taken and **authenticated** by Nancy Sinatra Sr. Each book contains **a numbered certificate of authenticity**, **signed by Sinatra's children - Nancy Sinatra, Frank Sinatra Jnr., and Tina Sinatra.**

The book is signed by the whole family:

> This spectacular 400-page book - which comes in luxury clam-shell case - **is signed by Nancy Sinatra, Frank Sinatra Jnr., and Tina Sinatra** and includes a rare and unpublished signed print of a photograph of Frank Sinatra taken by Nancy Sinatra Snr (see
>   image below, middle of the row).

At the end of the page, many preview pictures are found along with the picture you're skeptical about.

[image]

Additionally, the book is available officially on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1851498036) along with the picture also:

[image]

> Who shot the image?

officialnj350.com [says](http://officialnj350.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Frank-Sinatra-and-the-Hoboken-Four.-It-Happened-Here-New-Jersey.-Image-Credits.pdf) in a PDF document that Michael Ochs Archives shot the image and it is published on Getty Images.

[image]

> Is this photograph of Frank Sinatra as a 10 year old?

Not necessarily. It is Frank Sinatra, but it is [reported](http://www.buzzfeed.com/leonoraepstein/this-photo-of-a-young-frank-sinatra-will-make-you-go-omg#.jgk8LvJ2Z) that the picture is undated. He could be 8, 10 or 12, etc... The article says:

> Behold: It’s Frank Freakin’ Sinatra as a young boy. The photo is undated, however Frank looks to be about 10-years-old.